# What is the fastest way to get the number of neighbor nodes with NetworkX?

Tags: python, performance, networkx

Here is the benchmark testing a few options:

```
import numpy as np, timeit as ti, networkx as nx
from more_itertools import ilen

g = nx.ladder_graph(1000)
n = g.number_of_nodes()

fun = f'sum(len(g.adj[i]) for i in range(n))'
t = 1000 * np.array(ti.repeat(stmt=fun, setup='', globals=globals(), number=1, repeat=100))
print(f'{fun}:  {np.amin(t):6.3f}ms  {np.median(t):6.3f}ms ')

fun = f'sum(len(g[i]) for i in range(n))'
t = 1000 * np.array(ti.repeat(stmt=fun, setup='', globals=globals(), number=1, repeat=100))
print(f'{fun}:  {np.amin(t):6.3f}ms  {np.median(t):6.3f}ms ')

fun = f'sum(sum(1 for _ in g.neighbors(i)) for i in range(n))'
t = 1000 * np.array(ti.repeat(stmt=fun, setup='', globals=globals(), number=1, repeat=100))
print(f'{fun}:  {np.amin(t):6.3f}ms  {np.median(t):6.3f}ms ')

fun = f'sum(ilen(g.neighbors(i)) for i in range(n))'
t = 1000 * np.array(ti.repeat(stmt=fun, setup='', globals=globals(), number=1, repeat=100))
print(f'{fun}:  {np.amin(t):6.3f}ms  {np.median(t):6.3f}ms ')
```

and the results with Python 3.10.6 on my PC:

```
sum(len(g.adj[i]) for i in range(n)):   0.733ms   0.738ms 
sum(len(g[i]) for i in range(n)):   0.847ms   0.884ms 
sum(sum(1 for _ in g.neighbors(i)) for i in range(n)):   0.964ms   0.977ms 
sum(ilen(g.neighbors(i)) for i in range(n)):   1.335ms   1.362ms
```

`len(g.adj[i])` is the fastest method I found. Is there a faster way to get the number of neighbor nodes with NetworkX?

Note that I'm checking the number of neighbors for each node of the graph sequentially, which is my use case scenario. I much prefer this method than a single node micro-benchmark.

Comment: If the goal is to find the sum of degrees of all nodes, then you can use `g.number_of_edges()*2`. If you want the degree of a single node `i`, then  `g.degree(i)`.

Comment: @bb1 It's the latter, as stated. `g.degree(i)` is slightly slower than `len(g.adj[i])`, though.

Comment: @bb1 `g.degree[i]` is by far the fastest of them all, OTOH.